# Unable to re-render span tags in JSX that are saved in state in react.js

Tags: reactjs, render, state

I am building a battleship game and send a request to my server when a user clicks on a tag. That click is registered in my "fire" method, this method sends a post request to my server and my server responds with "Miss" "Hit" etc... my issue is that I am unable to update the value of my span tags to a 1 rather than the default 0. This way I can show users that they have hit or missed a ship. In the snippet below I think my error may stem from me initially loading my span tags in under a

tag, and that these tags are not updated like I think they are. If anyone has some advice on how I could get the result im looking for that would be greatly appreciated!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      boardData: [],
      test: 0
    }
  }

  fire(e) {
    var boardLetter;
    var boardNumber = e.charAt(1);
    if(e.charAt(0) === "A") {
      boardLetter = 0;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "B") {
      boardLetter = 1;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "C") {
      boardLetter = 2;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "D") {
      boardLetter = 3;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "E") {
      boardLetter = 4;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "F") {
      boardLetter = 5;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "G") {
      boardLetter = 6;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "H") {
      boardLetter = 7;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "I") {
      boardLetter = 8;
    } else if(e.charAt(0) === "J") {
      boardLetter = 9;
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/fire', {
      boardPiece: e
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data ', data.data, this.state.test);
      // this.state.boardData[0][1].props.children = 1
      this.setState({test: 1});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err ', err);
    })
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];
      var row = [];
      for(var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
      row.push(<span className={letters[count] + j} key={letters[count] + j} onClick={this.fire.bind(this, letters[count] + j)}>{this.state.test}</span>);
      }
      this.state.boardData.push(row);
      count++;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('response: ', response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('response error ', err);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to Battleship</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="board">
          <p> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 </p>
          <p>A {this.state.boardData[0]}</p>
          <p>B {this.state.boardData[1]}</p>
          <p>C {this.state.boardData[2]}</p>
          <p>D {this.state.boardData[3]}</p>
          <p>E {this.state.boardData[4]}</p>
          <p>F {this.state.boardData[5]}</p>
          <p>G {this.state.boardData[6]}</p>
          <p>H {this.state.boardData[7]}</p>
          <p>I {this.state.boardData[8]}</p>
          <p>J {this.state.boardData[9]}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using `this.state.test`

Comment: Sorry, I already saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store only the basic data in state and move everything else into `render`. The following does not include all of your code, but it (1) initializes the board data in the constructor (2) generates the board, including the letters, only in `render`:

```
var letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super(props);

    // Construct default board data, which is a 2d-matrix
    // (an Array<Array<string>>) of either '-' for nothing, '0' for miss or '1'
    // for hit.
    var boardData = [];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for(var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        row.push('-');
      }
      boardData.push(row);
      count++;
    }

    this.state = {
      boardData: [],
      test: 0
    }
  }

  fire(x, y) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/fire', {
      boardPiece: letters[y] + x
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data ', data.data, this.state.test);
      this.state.boardData[x][y] = data.data;
      this.forceUpdate();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err ', err);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to Battleship</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="board">
          <p> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 </p>
          {this.state.boardData.map((values, y) =>
            <p key={y}>
              {letters[y]}{values.map((value, x) => 
                <span>
                  {' '}
                  <span className={letters[y]} key={x} onClick={this.fire.bind(this, x, y)}>
                    {value}
                  </span>
                </span>
              )}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How will I now be able to update the value of these "0's" in other methods? Edit: I see, setState works perfectly fine now. Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Right, exactly! Call `setState` to trigger a re-render.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to only update a single element at a time as I don't want the whole board switching to a "1" like it is now haha

Comment: Too bad I didn't see this, I solved it a slightly different way. I had to accommodate multiple boards, but I ended up with a very similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the components you create during `componentWillMount` render only the first time the component is mounted. So, you need to move that code either to the render method or use the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

Comment: When I use the componentWillReceiveProps method I am unable to render any 0's on the page, I am only able to render A, B, C, etc... When I have a componentWillReceiveProps and a componentWillMount it does not work either.

Comment: I was thinking more of moving the `<span>` you have to their own component and using `componentWillReceiveProps`. With the current code, you should place the code of `componentWillMount` on your `render`.

Comment: Could you give me a code example of how I would place the current code within my render? I appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to refactor your code, you're adding a bunch of `<span>` components to your state, and you shouldn't be doing that.